# ‘mutex’ in namespace ‘boost’ does not name a type

Tags: c++

I get this error when I try to compile the following code:

```
#include <boost/signals2/mutex.hpp>

class Log
{
    private:
        boost::mutex m_log;
...
}
```

The error I get when I try to compile is:

```
error: ‘mutex’ in namespace ‘boost’ does not name a type
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it is in the sub namespace

```
boost::signals2::mutex
```